# I keep getting NaN if there is not enough money, instead of logging to the console and returning

Tags: javascript

```js
var Business = function(income, upkeep, level, upgradeCost, inc1, out1) {
    this.income = income;
    this.upkeep = upkeep;
    this.level = level;
    this.upgradeCost = upgradeCost;
    this.change = function() {
      money = money + this.income - this.upkeep
    };
    this.upgrade = function() {
      var currMon = money;
      if (currMon > this.upgradeCost) {
        money = currMon - this.upgradeCost;
        if (this.income === 0) {
          this.income = this.income = inc1;
          this.upkeep = this.upkeep * out1;
        } else {
          this.income = this.income * 1.05;
          this.upkeep = this.upkeep * 1.05;
        }
        this.level++;
        this.upgradeCost = this.level * 32 + (100 * this.income);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    };
```

If there is not enough money, when I execute `.upgrade();` it changes money to `NaN`.

Comment: Show an example call that converts to `NaN`?

Comment: Also, the code you've pasted does not run.  It throws a variety of notices.  May I recommend that you get it to a complete, working state, and update the code above? Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: This `upgrade` function isn't even possible to run in current form.

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to make it easier to see where some of the errors are occurring. [edit] your question until you can click Run code snippet and see no errors, and see how running it ends up with `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are using `money` instead of `this.money` and you are not initializing `this.money` to zero or whatever default you want to use. I tried running

```
let bi = new Business(8000,90,1,100,1,2)
bi.upgrade()
```

In Node.js and got this error:

```
ReferenceError: money is not defined
    at Business.upgrade (repl:7:45)
```

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, money is a global variable, and I need it to cancel, if money is less than the upgrade cost.

Comment: If I declare money as a global variable, then calling the upgrade works for me in Node even if money is lower than the upgrade cost. I cannot replicate your issue. Could you please give a larger snippet to show more of what is going on in your code?

Comment: var money = 125;
var day = 1;
var Business = function(<--|-->)
  else {return;}
  };
};
var lemonadeStand = new Business(0, 0, 0, 1);
if(keyWentDown("l")) {
  lemonadeStand.upgrade();
}

Comment: sorry for the weird code, it didn't come out as planned

Comment: @DanielNewell I still cannot replicate the issue. The code appears to be behaving as expected. Be aware though when you are creating the lemonade stand you are leaving `inc1` and `out1` as undefined.

Comment: thanks! that fixed it, i can't believe i missed that :)